# Rename nested key in array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Using JS i am trying to rename `canBook -> quantity`, `variationsEN -> variations` and nested keys `valueEN -> value`

```
var prod = [{
    price: 10,
    canBook: 1
}, {
    price: 11,
    canBook: 2,
    variationsEN: [{
        valueEN: 1
    }, {
        valueEN: 2
    }]
}]
```

I was able to rename keys, but i dont have a clue how to rename the nested ones: `valueEN`

```
prod.map(p => ({
    quantity: p.canBook, variations:p.variationsEN
}))
```

Comment: You cannot "rename" the property of an object. You can only add a new and delete the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply the same trick again. Replace:

```
variations:p.variationsEN
```

with:

```
variations:(p.variationsEN || []).map(q => ({ value: q.valueEN }))
```

The additional `|| []` is to deal with cases where the property does not exist in your source object. In that case an empty array is produced for it.

Comment: Sounds good, but I got `TypeError: p.variationsEN is undefined`

Comment: Then the data is not as you depicted in your question. In that case you need to first test for the property's existence. See update.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursiv approach with an object for the renamed properties and build new object or arrays.

```js
function rename(value) {
    if (!value || typeof value !== 'object') return value;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.map(rename);
    return Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(value)
        .map(([k, v]) => [keys[k] || k, rename(v)])
    );
}

var keys = { canBook: 'quantity', variationsEN: 'variations', valueEN: 'value' },
    prod = [{ price: 10, canBook: 1 }, { price: 11, canBook: 2, variationsEN: [{ valueEN: 1 }, { valueEN: 2 }] }],
    result = rename(prod);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's indeed a JSON (as your tag seems to indicate), e.g. you get it as string from a server, you can use a  [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) function, such as:

```
var prod = JSON.parse(prodJSON, function (k, v) {
 if (k === "canBook") {
   this["quantity"] = v
 } else {
   return v
 }
});
```

(Of course you could always stringify in case you start from a JS Object and not from a JSON string, but in that case it would be an overkill)

Answer (score 0):

```
variations:p.variationsEN.map(q => { value: q.valueEN })
```

Comment: Sounds good, but I got `TypeError: p.variationsEN is undefined`

Comment: It can happen if you don't pass the second argument or the second argument is undefined